# Octave - accessing aray elements from within a function

Tags: octave

I want to populate an empty array, and then access individual elements from within a function.

```
a = [];

for i=1:10
  a(i)=i;
end

function display_a(k)
  a = a(k);
  disp(a);
end

display_a(5)
```

Here I receive an error:

> 'a' undefined near line 8, column 7

Which means that `a=a(k)` within the function is not recognized as my array `a`. Any idea on how to pull this off?

I tried declaring `a` as a global variable. Apart from my understanding that declaring global variables is not a good practice, my function returns the whole array instead of just one, specified element.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to pass the array into the function. Each function has its own scope, and does not see variables declared in other scores. Declare the function as `function display_a(a,k)`.

Comment: Besides, avoid assignments like `a = a(k)` because after that the array `a(:)` becomes a scalar `a` (unless this is really what you want). Use an intermediate variable `b=a(k); disp(b)` or even directly `disp(a(k))`

Comment: Thank you @CrisLuengo, that worked like a charm. In hindsight it's so obvious, I was aware of what the scope of the function is and tried to "solve" it by declaring a global variable, but I wasn't really able to connect all the dots myself - thanks! PierU, definitely, sorry about introducing the ambiguity into this example, I'd never do that in the actual working code.